# Amazon EC2 Instance Unable to stop/terminate Default-Environment Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am experimenting with Amazon EC2.

When I signup to EC2 and launched the console - I got a Default Instance already running.
I terminated the Default Instance and Launched Another instance - Windows 2008 with .net and SQL.

Now the issue is - I have 2 Instances running.
Unable to stop or Terminate the Defaul-Environment Instance.

I have setup the complete environment in the other instance - if I terminate that, all the setting will be lost.

I am afraid since 2 instances are running - I will be out of the free tier usage in 15 days only - and they will start charging.

Kindly advise.

Thanks
Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to lose your environment you can create an Image (AMI) for the instance where you have all your environment. Like this:

[image: Create Image]

Later, you can launch a new instance with the Image that you created. That instance will be an exact copy of the one that you create the Image (AMI) from.

The free tier only applies to a single instance, so if you have two instances running you will get charged for the second instance anyways.